# GraphQL: referencing other ids

Tags: nested, graphql

I have a series of tables like:

```
Person:
person_id
first_name
last_name

CompanyPerson
person_id
company_id

Company
company_id
name

OfficePerson
office_id
person_id

Office
office_id
company_id
address_1
address_2
...
```

How would I indicate to graphQL, that I the following information: firstName is "Joe", company name, office addresses (ONLY office addresses for which JOE belongs to).

```
people(firstName: "joe") {
  company {
    name
    office {
      address_1
      address_2
    }
  }
}
```

If this was a singular request, I could set the "context" to talk about "joe"

```
person(firstName: "joe") {
}
```

I could use the graphql query schema to add further context restrictions (user: "Joe")

Since this is for multiple people, I don't see a method further refining queries based on information provided in a previous object.

Using: Ruby latest; graphql-ruby latest;

Thank you,

-daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resolver function receives four argument, one of which is the `obj` -- the object returned from the previous field. For example, a resolver map could appear as followers, in relevant part:

```
    // Root query/entry pt.
    Query: {
        async user(obj, input, context) {
          try 
            return user; // returns type User
          } catch (e) {
           console.log('err', e);
          }
        },

   ......
    // NOT a root query/entry pt.
    User: {
        async followers(obj, input, context) {
          try {
           const followers = await getFollowersByUserId(obj.id);
           return followers;
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('err', e);
          }
       },
```

Above, after the root query for user returns, graphql knows to look to resolve fields on the User type -- in this case, for example, `followers`. The returned value from the user root query is available as the `obj` and can be used to resolve fields on User. This should hold true whether the query is resolving a single User, or an array of type User. While the above is in js this should hold true for ruby, although your schema may need ot be modified.